# Spring cloud config directory structure

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud

I have a working Spring cloud config server who provides configuration from a git repository. All configurations are stored in the root directory in the repository. They are named `{name}-{profile}.yml`.

I have changed the directory structure to `{name}/{profile}.yml`

When I `curl http://configserver:8888/appname/myprofile` the config server I get a json response but the propertySources is empty.

My spring cloud server config

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: http://git@git.host/scm/cas/application-config.git
```

Comment: `{name}/{profile}.yml` won't work. I'll give a more detailed answer in a bit (don't have time at the moment), wanted to leave a comment. You can use directories and regex's to manage sprawl. You can also use multiple git repositories (ie a repo per team).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths` to the configuration server application.yml.

```
   cloud:
     config:
       server:
         git:
           searchPaths: <directory>
```

Comment: can we have dir/subdir ?